# Java copy constructor and clone doesnt work

Tags: java, copy-constructor, cloneable

```
public class Stav implements Cloneable{
private int[] pole;

public Stav(int[] pole){
    this.pole = pole;
}
public Stav(Stav a){
    this.pole = a.pole;
}
public void move(boolean left){
    int empty = findEmpty();
    if(left){
        this.pole[empty] = this.pole[empty - 1];
        this.pole[empty - 1] = 0;
    }
    else{
        this.pole[empty] = this.pole[empty + 1];
        this.pole[empty + 1] = 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
Jednotka pom = fronta.remove();
Stav nStav = new Stav(pom.getStav().getPole());
Stav pomStav = new Stav(nStav);
```

and when i call

```
pomStav.move(false);
```

the value of nStav will change same as pomStav... somebody can help me with this? I have some more metods in code but its so long so I didnt copy here like findEmpty etc.

Comment: You are not calling the clone() method anyware, so you are not cloning anything.

Comment: Read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: `public Stav(Stav a) { int[] b = new int[a.pole.length]; System.arraycopy(a.pole, 0, b, 0, a.pole.length); this(b); }`

Answer (score 1):

```
public Stav(Stav a){
    this.pole = a.pole;
}
```

When you call this, the underlying `int[] pole` is shared between the two instances as you are copying the ***reference*** to the object. Instead of copying the reference, create a new array and copy the values:

```
public Stav( Stav a )
{
    this.pole = new int[ a.pole.length ];
    for( int i = 0; i < this.pole.length; ++i )
        this.pole[ i ] = a.pole[ i ];
}
```

Comment: Rather than manally copying the values, it'd be better to use System.arraycopy or Arrays.copyOf.

Comment: Since arrays implement `clone()` in a useful manner, I prefer to use that to copy them.  If you do it manually, though, then at least you should copy the elements via `System.arraycopy()` rather than via an explicit loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `Stav` instances to be independent of each other, then you have a problem here

```
public Stav(Stav a){
    this.pole = a.pole;
}
```

... and here

```
Stav nStav = new Stav(pom.getStav().getPole());
```

... or alternatively, here

```
public Stav(int[] pole){
    this.pole = pole;
}
```

.  The effect is that you are giving your `Stav` instances references to the *same* array for their `pole` members.  If you want them to be independent then you must give them *copies* of the array.  One way to do that would be to write your constructors like so:

```
public Stav(int[] pole){
    this.pole = ((pole == null) ? null : pole.clone();
}
public Stav(Stav a){
    this(a.pole);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor (and your default "clone" method) are doing a shallow copy:

```
this.pole = a.pole;
```

After the above statement, both this.pole and a.pole are references to the same array.  If you want to do a slightly-deeper copy, you could do

```
this.pole = Arrays.copyOf (a.pole, a.pole.length);
```

After this operation, changes to the arrays would not be propagated between instances - though changes to the *contents* of the arrays would be if they were non-primitive arrays.

If you want your object to also do a deep copy when cloned, you need to override the clone() method:

```
public Object clone() {
  return new Stav(this);
}
```

(Do note that cloning has a number of problems - I highly recommend reading the chapters on cloning in *Effective Java* if you're going to be doing significant work involving cloning.